# Collate setting on a column in SQL Server table not working

Tags: sql-server, collation

I have a table in SQL Server 2008 database hosted on a shared web hosting. I cannot change the collation of the database because I don't have permissions.
When I created the table, I set the collation for the columns that I want but it doesn't do anything and I still see `????` when I query the table. I tried `nvarchar` as well and it didn't work.

The table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[T_Client]
(
    [ClientID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ClientName] [varchar](200) collate Hebrew_CI_AI null ,
    [Address] [varchar](200) collate Hebrew_CI_AI null
)
```

Comment: How are you *inserting* that data. It's no good making the column an `nvarchar`, or a `varchar` with the right collation is you are doing `INSERT INTO [dbo].[T_Client] (ClientName, Address) VALUES('String that contains UTF-16 characters','Another String that contains UTF-16 characters');` as the database's collation will lose those characters.

Comment: Also, SQL Server 2008 has been completely unsupported for some time now; you should really be looking at upgrade paths.

Comment: @Larnu, Yes I use insert into statement that contains Hebrew values

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must ensure that the data is passed all the way to SQL Server using a format with compatible code points.  Since you don't have Hebrew as your database or instance collation a varchar variable can't be used to store the data.  So this

```
declare @d varchar(100) = 'שלום לך עולם' collate Hebrew_CI_AI 
select @d
```

outputs

```
???? ?? ????
```

In this scenario you have to pass the value to the databse as NVARCHAR

```
declare @d nvarchar(100) = N'שלום לך עולם' collate Hebrew_CI_AI 
select @d
```

You *could* use a varchar column with a Hebrew collation to store the data, but you should just use an nvarchar column.  Still use the collation to produce the desired sorting and comparision semantics.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your `INSERT`/`UPDATE` statements. Unless you define those values as an `nvarchar` then the characters outside the **databases** collation will be lost. This means you need to declare your parameters as an `nvarchar`. As a result I would suggest, instead, not changing the collation of the columns and changing them as an `nvarchar` and using an `nvarchar`s throughout your code.